# REST API on OpenShift - Failed to parse request

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, resteasy, openshift

I am developing a REST API using Java EE 6 on JBoss AS 7 and deploying it to an OpenShift application.

I have developed and tested the API locally using JBoss Developer Studio and JBoss 7.1.0.Final and it works as expected but when I push it back to OpenShift, a HTTP 400 is returned, 'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()'

I have used rhc to tail the JBoss logs and the exception is as follows:

```
2014/04/13 07:11:47,348 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher] (http--127.10.141.1-8080-1) Failed to parse request.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters
at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriBuilderImpl.buildFromValues(UriBuilderImpl.java:546) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriBuilderImpl.build(UriBuilderImpl.java:539) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractUriInfo(ServletUtil.java:54) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:187) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

I have read a few forums regarding 'You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters' but so far everything I have read talks about a regular expression bug and as I have said it works locally.

I have even stripped back my classes to simplify the problem but I still experience the same exception. I have included the simplified classes here for reference.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApiServlet extends Application {
}

@Path("/")
public class ApiResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    public Person getHelloWorld() {
        return new Person("Fred", "Bloggs");
    }
}
```

Here is the web.xml. It is very minimal because Java EE 6 allows the use of annotations.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="false" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Any thoughts or advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Please provide your web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

I added these lines to the web.xml (of course bypassing @ApplicationPath("/api") ...) :

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

The service :

```
@Path("/")
public class PersonService {

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Person getInfo() {
        return new Person("John", "Doe");
    }

}
```

The entity :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

My test project is named "WebServiceREST" on a JBoss server :

```
http://localhost:8080/WebServiceREST/api
```

The resulting XML code :

```
<person>
<firstName>John</firstName>
<lastName>Doe</lastName>
</person>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm? `@Path` is already given on the class. The resource will be available via `GET /api/`.